# How to show Excel ribbon when it is embedded in Webbrowser

Tags: wpf, excel, browser

Using the suggestion from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15760/How-to-Integrate-Excel-in-a-Windows-Form-Applicati), I managed to embed Excel 2007 in my WPF WebBrowser control. However, the ribbon doesn't show up. I tried various techniques and nothing makes it work.

I tried this:

```
 _application.ExecuteExcel4Macro("SHOW.TOOLBAR(\"Ribbon\",True)");
```

I also tried to run this from a macro after the Excel workbook is constructed,

```
Sub hide_ribbon()
    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro ("Show.Toolbar(""Ribbon"", False)")
End Sub
Sub show_ribbon()
    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro ("Show.Toolbar(""Ribbon"", True)")
End Sub
```

but it doesn't work either, although the same macro works fine in native Excel.

Also tried this:

```
    CommandBar cb = _workbook.CommandBars["Standard"];
    cb.Visible = true;
    cb.Enabled = true;
    cb.Position = MsoBarPosition.msoBarTop;
```

Or tried changing "Standard" to "Ribbon", but nothing works.

Ctrl+F1 doesn't work either.

Anybody got a clue?

Answer (score 2):

It took me over 3 weeks of digging to work this out - even then I still need to test that it all works as expected.

As you already know the ribbon is automatically hidden when embedding Excel and that you need to 'toggle' it back on again by sending an OLE command.

I assume that you are uisng the SHDocVw library wrapped in with an ActiveX container, in the manner described in the knowledge base article is article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304662 and that you have set up the appropriate registry entries to get the browser to display Excel docs (I am sure that you must have done if all you are missing is the Ribbon).

I am using C#, so you may have to mess about a bit in VBA.

The article entitled "WebOCHostVB.exe Hosts the WebBrowser Control in Visual Basic .NET" in the MS support knowledge base looks promising however, the URL is "support.microsoft.com/kb/311303"

Once the document is opened, call ExecWB on the browser as follows :

```
     object omissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value ;
     this.axExcelWebBrowser1.ExecWB(SHDocVw.OLECMDID.OLECMDID_HIDETOOLBARS,
                                    SHDocVw.OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER,
                                    ref omissing, ref omissing);
```

This should toggle the Ribbon state - as it is off when we start, a single call should make it display.  Doing this again should hide it - though I have not tried.

The constants are in the shdocvw.dll that you must reference from your project. Even though these are integer enumerations, I could not redefine them locally and get things to work.

You can find other OLE commands, that might also be useful for your application, here :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691264%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

I don't know why this has to be so difficult, or why the behaviour of Excel is not consistent with that of Word.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this is the only working technique. I just added this to my project. As for using this in WPF WebBrowser control, try:

var pComWebBrowser = typeof(WebBrowser).GetProperty("AxIWebBrowser2", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var objComWebBrowser = pComWebBrowser.GetValue(browser, null);
const int OLECMDID_HIDETOOLBARS = 24;
const int OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2;
((dynamic)objComWebBrowser).ExecWB(OLECMDID_HIDETOOLBARS, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER);